# Specifying imageView to resize as percentage of screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

In Android I need to have a simple layout to be designed using XML layout (rather than programming):

I need to have the following :

1- small image view on the left (centered vertically)

2- Three image views a bit larger beside each others (also centered vertically)

3- Small image view on the right side (centered vertically)

so the 5 images are adjacent horizontally and centered vertically.

This is simple, anyhow the question is how to specify the image views to resize as percentage of the screen height ?

So if I specify the three image items to be 60% of screen height, I expect the imageView to resize (including the source image) to be 60% of screen height.

Is it achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, Take a LinearLayout(Horizontal) and then to all the childs(Imageviews here) give `layout:height="0dp" and layout:weight=".6"` , try this first and update questions if you have any further

Comment: Thanks, it gave me a good hint. Anyhow I had to specify the width to "0px" , it won't work if height="0dp". A good link to this problem is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean